# Method of allylic and benzylic oxidation

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I am told that $\ce{MnO_2}$ oxidizes allylic and benzylic alcohols. However, what is the mechanism of this oxidation? All the professor had to offer me was that the metal ion, manganese 2+, chelates the substrate; there is some sort of interaction between a pi bond, the metal ion, and the electrophilic carbon atom bearing the hydroxyl group. No further explanation was given, and a Google search hasn't unearthed anything of use. What, therefore, is the mechanism of this oxidation? I would like to know more about the mechanism to better understand why $\ce{MnO_2}$ only touches allylic and benzylic alcohols rather than any vanilla alcohol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of those heterogenous reactions occurring on a surface which are  mechanistically messy. As expected for a reaction that occurs on the surface of a reagent, factors such as surface area and reagent preparation (freshness, surface contamination) are significant variables.  A free radical mechanism is generally accepted and a reasonable mechanism is posted below.

[image: reaction mechanism]

[image source](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQLBumtq_7DseSIOlZuuX8Wn1PV7isYjyHuUGf9-7kb3-mfL0hq&s)

When an allylic alcohol with stereochemistry (cis, trans) around the double bond is oxidized, the stereochemistry around the double is preserved.

[image: rxn example]

[image source](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQLBumtq_7DseSIOlZuuX8Wn1PV7isYjyHuUGf9-7kb3-mfL0hq&s)

This suggests that we are not really dealing with a free, long-lived radical intermediate, but rather a free radical held in close association with the manganese ion.

Comment: Hmm, it works for me.  Let me put the url here again in case anyone else has a problem.  http://www.citab.utad.pt/refbase/files/1890_JI-DONGLOU2011.pdf

Comment: The link does not work

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz I've added the mechanism directly to the answer.